# Formatting report file using shell script

Tags: shell, unix, report

I have thousand of records in one text file in following format

report.txt

Record #: 1
   Emp name: ABC
   Address: LMN
   Mobile no: 1111111111 
   Date of birth: 31/12/2099

Record|Emp name|Address|Mobile no| Date of birth
   1|ABC|LMN|1111111111|31/12/2099

Record #: 2
   Job name: XYZ
   Address: PQR
   Mobile no: 1111111111
   Date of birth: 31/12/2099

Required output_file

output_file.txt

Record|Emp name|Address|Mobile no| Date of birth
   1|ABC|LMN|1111111111|31/12/2099
   2|XYZ|QRT|9999999999|31/12/2999

Is there any way to do this using shell scripting or any other language?

Comment: Please provide any solution for this question using shell script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring Batch. You are in a very simple usecase of this framework. 
I recommend you to follow tutorials on this subject [here](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/spring-batch-tutorial/).

Comment: Thank you @Aurelien.. Actually I am not aware about this framework. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: I think there is another way with shell but unfortunately I am not aware of it. I give you this answer because you mentioned "any other language" in your question.